# What happened to the “play to” functionality in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, language, windows-10-upgrade, play-to

Before I upgrade to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1, I could stream videos or images to my smart tv using the [play to](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/use-play-to) functionality by simply triggering the context menu with a right click on the video/image file.

Since I upgraded, things seems to no longer be that simple anymore *(`play to`sub menu disappeared in the context menu)*.
So how to do the same in Windows 10 ?

Comment: It still exists.  If it is missing then the DLNA device isn't reachable.

Comment: @Ramhound : the device is reachable from my android tablet, and my tablet can reach my computer. I can also ping the device from my computer.

Comment: Well the feature is still there but will only appear if Windows can see the DLNA capable device

Comment: @Ramhound : Ok, and sorry : they renamed it from`play to`to`effectuer une conversion de type (transtypage) vers l'appareil`which means`make a conversion of type (change type) to the device` *(completely meaningless)*. As there are many entries, I didn’t found it immediately.